# How is OpenID implemented?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

**How would you design and implement OpenID components?**

(Was "How does OpenId work")

I realize this question is somewhat of a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69076/openid-login-workflow), and yes, I have read [the spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) and the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

After reading the materials mentioned above, I still don't have a complete picture in my head of how each step in the process is handled.  Maybe what's missing is a good workflow diagram for how an implementation of OpenID works.

I'm considering incorporating OpenID into one of my applications to accomodate a B2B single-sign-on scenario, and I will probably go with [DotNetOpenID](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/) instead of trying to implement it myself, but I still want a better grasp of the particulars before I get started.

Can anyone recommend books or websites that do a good job of explaining it all?  It wouldn't hurt to have an answer that covers the basics here on this site as well.

[Edit]

I changed the title to be more implementation-specific, since there are obviously plenty of places to get the ten-thousand-foot view.

Comment: Sorry but i've had posts explaining Vista's disk usage deleted for not being programing.

Comment: Disagree, this is programming related.

Comment: perhaps it should be "how is OpenID implemented in language x or on platofrm y" ?

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://enthusiasm.cozy.org/archives/2005/05/openid-part-iii-pingpong/) has a nice flow diagram.

I found this link on the [OpenID Wiki](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run%20your%20own%20identity%20server), you might want to check there for more resources.

Comment: Steps 12-13, 18, and 19 are not fully disclosed.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Joseph Smarr's [Recipe for OpenID-Enabling Your Site](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe).

I haven't read the DotNetOpenID docs, but I would hope whatever implementation you choose would also have some overview documentation and/or examples to illustrate usage of the API.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Security Now podcast, [episode 95](http://www.grc.com/sn/notes-095.htm). ([Actually audio](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm#95))

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has a great article on OpenID where he shares his experiences:

[OpenID: Does The World Really Need Yet Another Username and Password?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001121.html)

There are some links to tutorials on the official OpenID site:

http://openid.net/developers/

You can get a nice login-control for OpenID (which also is used here on stackoverflow) here:

http://www.idselector.com/

Comment: I read that, and it's a good high level overview, but I guess I'm looking for one level below that.  I might change the name of the question to "how would you implement OpenId" or "how does an openid implementation work?".

Answer (score 1):

Also related:

The [super-famous talk by Dick Hardt on Identity 2.0](http://identity20.com/media/OSCON2005/), I suppose almost everyone has watched it, but if you haven't it is a must see.

It is more about the reasoning of the need of things like Open ID and not necessarily about their implementation, though.